# xcodebuild for -sdk iphonesimulator inside "Run Script" results a codesign error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcodebuild

This is the error I'm getting:

> CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Application' in
>   SDK 'Simulator - iOS 9.2

Or

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type
>   'Application' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 9.2'

When trying to `xcodebuild` one of my projects.

I'm reproduced the problem by creating a workspace with two empty projects.
I've edited `test1` `Build Phases` -> `Run Script` with this:

```
xcodebuild -project test2/test2.xcodeproj -scheme test2 -sdk iphonesimulator
```

And got the above error.

This error will occur only when running `xcodebuild` inside `Run Script` & when `-sdk` is `iphonesimulator`

- Running the identical command from the terminal will build fine.
- Running the above command with `-sdk iphoneos` from `Run Script` will
  build fine.
- Running test2 from the regular Xcode Build \ Play button will build
  fine.

I must clarify that the code signing identities and provisions are correct and the app builds fine from the regular Xcode build or from the terminal.

I've read quite a few topics online regarding the above error but none of them seemed to describe the above scenario which looks like an Xcode bug.

Thanks

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out on your own?

Answer (score 1):

I've opened a bug to apple and it was closed as duplicate. I've also found this open radar regarding the issue:

http://www.openradar.me/23857648

Adding the `destination` argument didn't change much here (some one suggested this in the radar comments)

In my specific scenario I need to build both platforms in order to lipo both into one. Because of this bug I can only do it if building for iphonesimulator. It will do a regular build for iphonesimulator and xcodebuild for iphoneos.

Building for iphoneos and xcodebuild for iphonesimulator will fail as written in the question.

If your scenario is different than mine you can put this in your run script to differentiate between the two:

```
if [[ $SDK_NAME == *"simulator"* ]]
then
xcodebuild -scheme UniversalLib -sdk iphonesimulator
else
xcodebuild -scheme UniversalLib
fi
```